# Is there a way to directly share a private google spreadsheet(organization restricted) to others?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting up a google spreadsheet to give my client to use. 
However, we both are using organization ID's meaning that we cannot directly share our sheets to one another. 
So, I have to download and send the google spreadsheet but the formulas and app scripts break if I download it as an xlsx file. 
Is there a way to share the file??.. I don't want to have to borrow my client's laptop and do the process over again. 
(BTW, of course there's no such option as "Set the sheet public" or "Allow anyone with link to access") 
I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you join shared drives?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that’s not possible either.

Comment: I guess the big part of the issue that you want your scripts to work in excel and that's not going to happen.  So if you can't get your client to use google sheets then you're probably wasting you time.

Comment: Speak to your admin about how to do this, as there can be many ways but ultimately all depend on your (and your clients) OU restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to share files that have restrictions in place to prevent them from being shared.

Thankfully there seems to be no way to do that.

As a workaround you could potentially manually copy the data and script into a new sheet, you would now be the owner, leaving you the possibility of sharing it. Though of course, you should check with your admin to ensure that this is not violating any company policy.